# Probability that $n$ vectors drawn randomly from $\mathbb{R}^n$ are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, random-matrices

Let's take $n$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ at random. What is the probability that these vectors are linearly independent? (i.e. they form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$)

(of course the problem is equivalent of "taken a matrix at random from $M_{\mathbb{R}}(n,n)$, what is the probability that its determinant $\neq 0$)

Don't know if this question is difficult to answer or not. Please share any information about it! :-)

(the $n$ vectors are meant with real values, I'm interested in solutions in $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$ or whatever fields you like)

Comment: What distribution are the $n$ vectors taken from? (By the way, the title has $N$ where the body has $n$.)

Comment: the n vectors are taken from R :-)

Comment: But for which distribution?

Comment: Distribution (sort of) must be specified. But if the components are chosen independently and at random from a continuous distribution, the probability is $1$.

Comment: uniformly at random.. @AndréNicolas can you explain it? :-)

Comment: How do you draw a number uniformly at random from $R$?

Comment: @Ant There is no "ordinary" uniform probability distribution on all of  $\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{R}^k$).

Comment: So say uniformly on $[0,1]$. Assume that for $k$ vectors where $k\lt n$, the probability is $1$. These form a subspace of dimension $k$, and therefore of measure $0$. So with probability $1$ the next vector chosen is not in that subspace.

Comment: suppose you could take uniform distribution on $S^{n-1}$ then the probability will be 1 which should be easy. trivial in $R^1$, and when you have $n-1$ vectors in $R^n$ then the probability of drawing a vector in the hyperplane they form is zero because the Lebesgue measure of this hyperplane is 0. it's still just heuristics with assumption of the probability mentioned before

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As others have pointed out the main problem is what "taking a vector at random" means. Probability theory requires that one specifies a certain probability measure on ${\mathbb R}^n$ before one can make any predictions about outcomes of experiments concerning chosen vectors. E.g., if it is totally unlikely, meaning: the probability is zero, that a vector with $x_n\ne 0$ is chosen, then the probability that $n$  vectors chosen independently are linearly independent is $\>=0$, since with probability $1$ they all lie in the plane $x_n=0$.

A reasonable starting point could be installing a  *rotational invariant* probability measure. As the length of the $n$ chosen vectors does not affect their linear dependence or independence this means that we are chosing $n$ independent vectors uniformly distributed on the sphere $S^{n-1}$. (This informal description has a precise mathematical meaning.)

Under this hypothesis the probability that the $n$ chosen vectors $X_k$ are linearly independent is $=1$.

*Proof.* The first vector $X_1$ is linearly independent with probability $1$, as $|X_1|=1$. Assume that $1< r\leq n$  and that the first $r-1$  vectors are linearly independent with probability $1$. Then with probability $1$ these $r-1$ vectors span a subspace $V$ of dimension $r-1$, which intersects $S^{n-1}$ in an $(r-2)$-dimensional "subsphere" $S_V^{r-2}$. This subsphere has $(n-1)$-dimensional measure $0$ on $S^{n-1}$. Therefore the probability that $X_r$ lies in this subsphere is zero. It follows that with probability $1$ the vectors $X_1$, $\ldots$, $X_{r-1}$, $X_r$ are linearly independent.

Comment: thank you! This is what I was looking for, I'm not an expert on probability so my question is rather naive, but thanks for answering :-)

Answer (score 0):

This depend of how you takes the vectors. For the case $n=2$, for example, if you have a vector $v_1$, the probability that you get a vector LD with $v_1$ is $0$. So, the probability that you get two vector LI is 1.