# Where do 4 planes in 4D space intersect?

Tags: linear-algebra

Problem 8 in problem set 2.1 in Gilbert Strang's Linear Algebra says

"Normally 4 planes in a 4-dimensional space meet at a ____."

---

Let the four dimensions be $x,y,z,w$. In three dimensions, a plane is defined to be a two dimensional surface that extends infinitely. A plane satisfies some equation of the form $ax+by+cz=n$. Abstractly extending this definition to $4$D space, a plane would satisfy some equation of the form $ax+by+cz+dw=n$. First off, is this correct? Secondly, I'm not sure where $4$ of such planes would meet.

Could someone please help?

Comment: The equation $ax+by+cz=n$ defines a plane through its normal vector $(a,b,c)$. (If that vector has length $1$, $n$ is the signed distance of the plane from the origin) If you carry this over formally to $\mathbb{R}^4$ the way you did you get a three dimensional subspace, which is orthogonal to $(a,b,c,d)$. From the question it is not clear whether this is what you want, or whether you want to consider two dimensional subspaces. In other words: what is the (general) definition of a plane in that book?

Comment: Doesn’t Strang refer to hyperplanes in dimensions >3?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not quite. What you are trying to define is called a *hyperplane*, not a plane. Basically, in an $n$-dimensional space, like $\mathbb{R}^n$, a hyperplane is derived by imposing one constraint on the space, like
$$
c_1 x_1 + c_2 x_2 + \ldots + c_n x_n = c_0,
$$
which makes hyperplane have dimension $n-1$. Then, intersecting 2 hyperplanes imposes another constraint, so the result will be $n-2$ dimensional, and the intersection of $n$ hyperplanes would have dimension $0$, i.e. be a single point.

---

The real question is, however, if this is what Gilbert Strang really means in the question. He is saying he is operating on *planes* (**not** hyperplanes). Planes in any space are defined as 2D objects, so even though in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (which is 3-D), the plane and the hyperplane are the same notion (which explains where the name *hyper*plane comes from), in higher dimensions that is no longer the case. In particular, in $\mathbb{R}^4$, plane is still 2D, so requires 2 constraints, not 1, as a hyperplane would.

Two planes usually intersect in a line, but 4 planes is a different story...

Comment: Indeed. And, in any case, two 2-dimensional planes in 4-space typically intersect in a point. :) ... and four 2-dimensional planes in 4-spaces typically have empty intersection...

Comment: @paulgarrett The solution manual disagrees with your answer. See problem 8's solution 
in problem set 2.1 here: https://math.mit.edu/~gs/linearalgebra/ila_sol5_ch02.pdf

Comment: @SakshamSethi, well, referring directly to reality, the 2D planes $x=0=y$ and $z=0=w$ intersect just at $\{0\}$. Also, the "constraint-counting" argument given in this answer gives the same outcome for "generic" intersections. Sure, four 3D-planes (=hyperplanes) in 4-space generically intersect in a point. It's not good if Strang inadvertently used "plane" for "hyperplane"...

Comment: @paulgarrett Yes, most likely Strang used "plane" for "hyperplane"

Answer (score 1):

Assume Strang meant hyperplane. A hyperplane in $\mathbb R^n$ is generally defined as all points $\mathbf x$ satisfying $\mathbf n \cdot \mathbf x = c$, where $\mathbf n$ is the normal vector and $c$ is a constant real number. If $n-1$ coordinates are known, the last is determined, so the hyperplane has dimension $n-1$.

In this case our intersection can be represented as 4 simultaneous equations:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf n_1 \cdot \mathbf x &= c_1 \\ 
\mathbf n_2 \cdot \mathbf x &= c_2 \\ 
\mathbf n_3 \cdot \mathbf x &= c_3 \\ 
\mathbf n_4 \cdot \mathbf x &= c_4 \\
\end{align}
$$

or a matrix equation
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf n_1 \\
\mathbf n_2 \\
\mathbf n_3 \\
\mathbf n_4
\end{bmatrix}
\mathbf x 
=
\begin{bmatrix}
c_1 \\
c_2 \\
c_3 \\
c_4 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

If the normals are picked to point in uniformly random directions, with probability 1 all are linearly independent (see [Probability that $n$ vectors drawn randomly from $\mathbb{R}^n$ are linearly independent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432447/probability-that-n-vectors-drawn-randomly-from-mathbbrn-are-linearly-ind)), so the matrix of normals is full rank and there is one solution for $\mathbf x$ at a point. You don't have to use matrices to solve this, but this is how you would get a computer to solve given actual values.